# AngularJS ui-router form submission

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS + ui-router to make some wizard with nested forms and routes.

here is the main form:

```
    <div  id="form-container-wizard">
        <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <form name="addItem_form"  ng-submit="submitForm()">


                <div class="page-header text-center">
                    <h2>Post Your Item</h2>

                    <!-- the links to our nested states using relative paths -->
                    <!-- add the active class if the state matches our ui-sref -->
                    <div id="status-buttons-wizard" class="text-center">
                        <a ng-class="{ disabled: ItemCheckPass }" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".item"> <span></span>Item</a>
                        <a ng-class="{ disabled: !ItemCheckPass || LocationCheckPass}" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".location"><span></span>Location</a>
                        <a ng-class="{ disabled: !ItemCheckPass || !LocationCheckPass || AccountCheckPass}"ng-show="!IsAuthenticated" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".account"><span></span>Account</a>
                        <a ng-class="{ disabled: !ItemCheckPass || !LocationCheckPass || !IsAuthenticated && !AccountCheckPass }"ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".social"><span></span>Social</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- wizard container -->
```

here is the routing for the form:

```
    .state('post_add', {
        url: '/post_add',
        templateUrl: '/view/post_wizard/form.html',
        controller: 'postWizardMainController',
        abstract:true
    })
    .state('post_add.item', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: '/view/post_wizard/form-item.html',
        controller: 'postWizardController'
    })
    .state('post_add.location', {
        url: '/location',
        templateUrl: '/view/post_wizard/form-location.html',
        controller: 'postWizardController'
    })
    .state('post_add.account', {
        url: '/account',
        templateUrl: '/view/post_wizard/form-account.html',
        controller: 'postWizardController'
    })
    .state('post_add.social', {
        url: '/social',
        templateUrl: '/view/post_wizard/form-social.html',
        controller: 'postWizardController'
    });
```

each view contains a partial form and store the form elements values to `$scope.AddItem` object by using ng-models like `<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="AddItem.email" ng-minlength=3 ng-maxlength=30 required>`

`postWizardMainController` used to keep the validation variables and methods.

So, **the problem is:**

**option 1:** the code is as listed here, `<form name="addItem_form"  ng-submit="submitForm()">` is not getting submitted by `<input type="submit" ng-disabled="addItem_form.$invalid" class="btn btn-orange" value="Post An Ad">` located in the last of form views.

**option 2:** i put the `submitForm()` into the ng-click in the last form, and locate `submitForm()` function in the `postWizardMainController`. In this option, the `submitForm()` function is called, bit no objects are passed into it. `$scope.AddItem` is `undefined`.

So, **the question is:**
How can i submit the form and pass `$scope.AddItem` object into submission, which must contain the data from all the nested forms.

Comment: Have you tried passing the addItem into the function `ng-submit="submitForm(AddItem)"`, because my guess is that it isn't accessible by the scope where you implemented the `submitForm` function

Comment: i also guess so. yes i tried. undefined. Yes, not accessible for unknown reason

Comment: is all of this nested in some parent controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to declare `$scope.AddItem = {}` in `postWizardMainController`